# How can I display several fields from one column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM0lQ.jpg)

I have a database about films. Each film has several producers, actors and can be referred to several genres. I'm trying to display all this information.

How should I change my request to get different information from, for example, a1.actor_id and a2.actor_id

Take a link to see my database on GitHub 
https://github.com/J4Mary/lesson11/blob/master/films13.sql

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'Name: "',
    films.film_name,
    '" (', films.year, '). Rating: ',
    films.rating,
    ' Genre: ',
    g1.genre, ', ',
    g2.genre, ', ',
    g3.genre,
    '. Directors: ',
    p1.producer_name, ', ',
    p2.producer_name,
    '. Actors: ',
    a1.actor_name, ', ',
    a2.actor_name, ', ',
    a3.actor_name
) AS info 
FROM 
    films
    INNER JOIN s_film_genre ON (films.id_film=s_film_genre.film_id)
    INNER JOIN genres AS g1 ON (s_film_genre.genre_id=g1.genre_id)
    INNER JOIN genres AS g2 ON (s_film_genre.genre_id=g2.genre_id)
    INNER JOIN genres AS g3 ON (s_film_genre.genre_id=g3.genre_id)
    INNER JOIN s_film_producer ON (films.id_film=s_film_producer.id_film) 
    INNER JOIN producers AS p1 ON (s_film_producer.id_producer=p1.id_producer) 
    INNER JOIN producers AS p2 ON (s_film_producer.id_producer=p2.id_producer) 
    INNER JOIN s_film_actor ON (films.id_film=s_film_actor.id_film)
    INNER JOIN actors AS a1 ON (s_film_actor.id_actor=a1.id_actor)
    INNER JOIN actors AS a2 ON (s_film_actor.id_actor=a2.id_actor)
    INNER JOIN actors AS a3 ON (s_film_actor.id_actor=a3.id_actor);
```

Comment: Please format your code. Also take a look as [ask]. Following that as a template for your qquestion greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactoty answer.

Comment: Please add your table creation queries

Answer (score 0):

When you need to show some fields from different records and process them together, you should think about using aggregate functions. In that case we have I was thinking about **GROUP_CONCAT** from **mysql**, but in **postgres** there's no such function, so I have found **ARRAY_AGG** function, and **ARRAY_TO_STRING** to make it string, not an array.

**ARRAY_AGG** makes some copies inside, when it goes to many joins, but it allows to use **DISTINCT**, so it is not a problem.

Enjoy!

```sql
SELECT 
    film_name,
    year,
    rating,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT genre), ', ') AS genres,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT producer_name), ', ') AS producers,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT actor_name), ', ') AS actors
FROM
    films 
    INNER JOIN s_film_genre ON (id_film = film_id)
    INNER JOIN genres USING (genre_id)
    INNER JOIN s_film_producer USING(id_film)
    INNER JOIN producers USING(id_producer)
    INNER JOIN s_film_actor USING(id_film)
    INNER JOIN actors USING(id_actor)

GROUP BY
    film_name,
    year,
    rating;
```